# how to send a custom error responses instead of errors generated by web APIs in java webaplication project

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
try {   
            ---some code---          
         }
         LogMsg.info("Address Created id " + reference.getId());
         builder = Response.ok(reference.getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // Handle generic exceptions
       Map<String, String> responseObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
        responseObj.put("error", e.getMessage());
        LogMsg.error(e.getMessage());
        builder = Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(responseObj); 
        }
    return builder.build();
```

Here i want to send my custom message which is belong to custom error handling class.instead of Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST i want to send my own message.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your `web.xml`. Add following as a child of `web-app` element.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error-404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

and create your custom error-404.jsp file

Comment: thank you Mr.czpona.Actually i need to send my own message for every error message generated in server side.

Comment: please refer my above description for your understanding